# Port forwarding but "refused to connect"

Tags: router, port-forwarding

**192.168.1.1:7070** this works

[image: 1]

Then I go to my router settings and set this rule:

[image: 2]

and when I enter `http://46.190.85.34:7070/` to my URL page, this is what I see:

[image: 3]

I have made an `inbound rule` in windows firewall to allow port 7070. What am I missing ?

Comment: It may be that your ISP does not allow loop-back: you need to test from a different ISP domain (at work, at friend's house, in internet café, etc). You may be able to test with a proxy, but I don't know a proxy which allows the connection port to be specified.

Comment: @AFH http://www.canyouseeme.org/ says that `can't see 46.190.85.34 on port 7070` . Can you see it ?? Now its up and running

Comment: @Shiro The connection has timed out

The server at 46.190.85.34 is taking too long to respond.

Comment: No, I can't see it. Can you try disabling your firewall temporarily? You may need to restart your server.

Comment: @AFH I have restarted my router and IP changed to `37.6.116.227:7070/` now, I disabled firewall, still nothing.

Comment: @AFH It's the **router** that needs to support loop back. Most domestic grade routers don't. See [What is NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning?](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/)

Comment: @Shiro Same error.

Comment: That looks like ADSL.   I recall a time when ADSL site were often configured to be PPPoe nodes.  Some times they filtered access. Sometimes what you saw on the router was a real IP address, nut one private to the ISP.   Is 46.190.85.34 what you see as the routers status page for the external IP,  or did a web site like `http://network-tools.com/` give it to you.   That is not a bad place to go if you want to ping and traceroute inward instead of out.

Comment: sorry, I hit return early and had to edit.  Don't know what imcomplete comment you saw.   PPPoe is using a PPP protocol, like used to be used for dialup internet.  Some ADSL (your broad band connection) providers use that as an en-capsuling protocol to transport their customer internet connection, only with ADSL instead of a telephone modem.   A long way to say that maybe you do not have a simple internet connection

Comment: @infixed So what should i do then ? `adsl-227.37.6.116.tellas.gr` this takes me to my router page also, still `7070` port not working

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for correcting me on that: I always assumed that a public address went to the IP and it was there that loop-back was prevented, as I couldn't see why the router shouldn't handle the returning packets. And I've just found out I can now do loop-back with my recently replaced router!

Comment: @shiro.  If its going to be a long debugging session, we should probably chat.  But where I'd start would be by looking at the IP address your router talks to the rest of the world with.  It may be your changing IP addresses are actually proxies that your ISP makes you use. can you go to command line and do `ipconfig /all` and see what IP your "default gateway" is?

Comment: @infixed can you chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/37194/port-forwarding-but-refused-to-connect?tab=general) ? I am not sure I did this correctly